# Not fully understanding how SE works across the dplyr verbs

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to understand how SE works in `dplyr` so I can use variables as inputs to these functions. I'm having some trouble with understanding how this works across the different functions and when I should be doing what. It would be really good to understand the logic behind this.

Here are some examples:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)


a <- c("x", "y", "z")
b <- c(1,2,3)
c <- c(7,8,9)

df <- data.frame(a, b, c)
```

The following is exactly why i'd use SE and the `*_` variant of a function. I want to change the name of what's being mutated based on another variable.

```
#Normal mutate - copies b into a column called new
mutate(df, new = b)

#Mutate using a variable column names. Use mutate_ and the unqouted variable name. Doesn't use the name "new", but use the string "col.new"
col.name <- "new"
mutate_(df, col.name = "b")

#Do I need to use interp? Doesn't work
expr <- interp(~(val = b), val = col.name)
mutate_(df, expr)
```

Now I want to `filter` in the same way. Not sure why my first attempt didn't work.

```
#Apply the same logic to filter_. the following doesn't return a result
val.to.filter <- "z"
filter_(df, "a" == val.to.filter)

#Do I need to use interp? Works. What's the difference compared to the above?
expr <- interp(~(a == val), val = val.to.filter)
filter_(df, expr)
```

Now I try to `select_`. Works as expected

```
#Apply the same logic to select_, an unqouted variable name works fine
col.to.select <- "b"
select_(df, col.to.select)
```

Now I move on to `rename_`. Knowing what worked for `mutate` and knowing that I had to use `interp` for `filter`, I try the following

```
#Now let's try to rename. Qouted constant, unqouted variable. Doesn't work
new.name <- "NEW"
rename_(df, "a" = new.name)

#Do I need an eval here? It worked for the filter so it's worth a try. Doesn't work 'Error: All arguments to rename must be named.'
expr <- interp(~(a == val), val = new.name)
rename_(df, expr)
```

Any tips on best practice when it comes to using variable names across the `dplyr` functions and when `interp` is required would be great.

Comment: I'm particularly in favor of just using `get` and the standard forms. If I use `get('a') == val.to.filter` I get what I'm after and don't have to mess around with strange formula forms of my filters

Comment: `mutate_(df, col.name = "b")` definitely does not do what you say it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences here are not related to which `dplyr` verb you are using. They are related to where you are trying to use the variable. You are mixing whether the variable is used as a function argument or not, and whether it should be interpreted as a `name` or as a `character` string.

#### Scenario 1:

You want to use your variable as an argument name. Such as in your `mutate` example.

```
mutate(df, new = b)
```

Here `new` is the name of a function argument, it is left of a `=`. The only way to do this is to use the `.dots` argument. Like

```
col.name <- 'new'
mutate_(df, .dots = setNames(list(~b), col.name))
```

Running just `setNames(list(~b), col.name)` shows you how we have an expression (`~b`), which is going right of the `=`, and the name is going left of the `=`.

#### Scenario 2:

You want to give only a variable as a function argument. This is the simplest case. Let's again use `mutate(df, new = b)`, but in this case we want `b` to be variable. We could use:

```
v <- 'b'
mutate_(df, .dots = setNames(list(v), 'new'))
```

Or simply:

```
mutate_(df, new = b)
```

#### Scenario 3

You want to do some combinations of variable and fixed things. That is, your expression should only be partly variable. For this we use `interp`. For example, what if we would like to do something like:

```
mutate(df, new = b + 1)
```

But being able to change `b`?

```
v <- 'b'    
mutate_(df, new = interp(~var + 1, var = as.name(v)))
```

Note that we `as.name` to make sure that we insert `b` into the expression, not `'b'`.

Comment: What is the significance of quotes in NSE? The documentation states that the inputs must be quoted, but that doesn't seem the be the case with the 'new' in your final example. I'm just trying to understand why. Thanks!

Comment: Everything after `=` needs to be quoted. Did you read `vignette('nse')`?